# no muestra valor al leer xml desde php

Tags: php, xml

Estoy tratando de leer unas etiquetas XML desde PHP con `simplexml_load_file`, pero no carga la información, asi que estoy tratando con la carga directa de los datos desde php - xml. Requiero leer las lineas de la **260** a la **305** que estan con la etiqueta `<cac:Item></cac:Item>`
he revisado y tratado con el siguiente código pero no me regresa ningun valor

```php
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<!-- (...) Aqui data irrelevante para el caso -->
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Note>MANIFIESTO 195054 PLACA JUH 858</cbc:Note>
<cbc:Note>Categoría: TRANSPORTE</cbc:Note>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="WSD">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">2700000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Description>SERVICIOS DE TRANSPORTE</cbc:Description>
<cac:StandardItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="" schemeID="999" schemeName="Estándar de adopción del contribuyente">01</cbc:ID>
</cac:StandardItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">2700000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="WSD">1.00</cbc:BaseQuantity>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Note>MANIFIESTO 175192 PLACA STR 275</cbc:Note>
<cbc:Note>Categoría: TRANSPORTE</cbc:Note>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="WSD">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1010000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Description>SERVICIOS DE TRANSPORTE</cbc:Description>
<cac:StandardItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="" schemeID="999" schemeName="Estándar de adopción del contribuyente">01</cbc:ID>
</cac:StandardItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">1010000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="WSD">1.00</cbc:BaseQuantity>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
<cac:InvoiceLine>
<cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
<cbc:Note>MANIFIESTO 175322 PLACA STR 275</cbc:Note>
<cbc:Note>Categoría: TRANSPORTE</cbc:Note>
<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="WSD">1.00</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
<cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP">1230000.00</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
<cac:Item>
<cbc:Description>SERVICIOS DE TRANSPORTE</cbc:Description>
<cac:StandardItemIdentification>
<cbc:ID schemeAgencyID="" schemeID="999" schemeName="Estándar de adopción del contribuyente">01</cbc:ID>
</cac:StandardItemIdentification>
</cac:Item>
<cac:Price>
<cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="COP">1230000.00</cbc:PriceAmount>
<cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="WSD">1.00</cbc:BaseQuantity>
</cac:Price>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
</Invoice>
XML;

$factura = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$namespaces = $factura -> getNamespaces(true);
$factura -> registerXPathNamespace('e', $namespaces['cac']);

foreach ($factura -> xpath('//e:InvoiceLine') as $m) {
    echo($m['Note']." <br/>");
    echo($m['ID']." <br/>");
    echo($m['InvoicedQuantity unitCode="WSD"']." <br/>");
    echo($m['LineExtensionAmount currencyID="COP"']." <br/>");
}
```

Gracias por la observaciones, realizo los ajustes en la pregunta de antemano agradezco la orientación que me puedan brindar

Comment: El código debe estar directamente en la pregunta, porque no todos tenemos acceso a ese tipo de sitios o, peor aún, si eliminas el archivo, la pregunta perderá todo sentido. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/547561/edit) para agregar el código relevante, no todo el proyecto, solo donde tratas de leer el XML y obtener los datos. Adicionalmente, explica en detalle cuál es el error que obtienes.

Comment: Edité la pregunta a como estaba inicialmente, en la dirección remota que incluiste ayer, para mejor comprensión, ya que hoy se entendía menos. Pero puedes volver a editarla si algo ha cambiado.